# In odoo 10 how can we add new fields to right side by inherting,right side does not have any fileds

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to add to the right side of `product` in view

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**views/stock.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

<record id="view_production_lot_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">stock.production.lot</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_production_lot_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <group name="main_group" position="inside">
            <group>
                <!-- Add your fields here. -->
            </group>
        </group>
    </field>
</record>

</odoo>
```

*Note*: You need to add the `stock` module the your custom module dependencies
and include the `views/stock.xml` file in your custom module manifest's `data` files
list.

Comment: Is it `<group name="main_group" position="inside">` or `<field name="main_group" position="inside">`

I tried both..First one produces an error and while I use second method,its not showing fields.. (Fields are showing under `internal refernce` using another third method

Comment: It should be `<group name="main_group" position="inside">`. Could you post what error you are getting? I have tried it locally and it worked ok for me.

Comment: `Element '<group name="product_id">' cannot be located in parent view`
Here product_id is the field name of `Product`

Comment: It works..
Thanks Naglis..
I was assigning the group name false